# How do I calculate percentage in php mysql table?

Tags: php, mysql, calculated-columns

I have a question related to a calculation of the percentage with php using mysql database.

I have three table month, revenue, overhead.

EX:

```
Month | Revenue | Overhead
Jan   | 2500    | 1000
Feb   | 1000    | 500
```

I would like to demonstrate the difference from one value to another using a percentage with php mysql. Now I need to show the values ​​already calculated, do that to more like php?

Sorry for my english.

Comment: basic high school math ...

Comment: mate, you can use basic math functions in mysql, and in PHP as well.  If this is a problem you probably should re-consider doing database & coding work...Sorry if I sound too harsh, but this is the reality of it.

Comment: Ok, i know, but i am a new in php and mysql

Answer (score 0):

```
$revenue = $row['revenue'];
$overhead = $row['overhead'];

$_div100 = $revenue / 100;

$percentage = $overhead / $_div100;

echo number_format($percentage, 2);
```

Comment: I feel bad, this doesn't really apply to PHP or MySQL that much.

Answer (score 0):

Once you receive the data back from the database in an array.. lets say in a variable called `$data`

you could do

```
<?php
foreach($data as $value){
    $percentage = $value['Overhead'] / $value['Revenue'] * 100;
    echo $value['month'] . " - " . $percentage . "%<br>";
}

?>
```

Comment: i got a error: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-13.1VC9\data\localweb\Projeto Financeiro\Sandbox\Inserir_Valor\listar.php on line 86

Comment: Have you loaded the data in the `$data` array with a MySQL function?

Comment: sorry I'm a new guy in php, how should I do this?